# Blender 2.8 - Cycles Render - Imported FBX object not properly rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, .fbx

I have a weird parallax distortion when I tried to render an imported fbx file on Blender 2.8. The rendered mode viewport and the final rendered image both look distorted. This felt like a normal related issue and recalculating normals didn't resolve the issue. Here's a quick gif:
[image: Gif]

Top View (Looks fine):
[image]

Front View (Distorted):
[image]

Geometry (Wireframe):
[image]

Any idea what might be causing this? I could be missing something obvious... Thanks in advance

Blend file:
https://gofile.io/?c=wGwpsm

Comment: what is the node setup for the material of that object? Would be easier if you share the blend file, so others could check what could be the issue. Have you imported that file to another software (ex.: Meshroom) with success?

Comment: I've added the blend file. Thanks!